# unidirectional vs bidirectional flatbed scanners

Tags: hardware-failure, scanner

Why does the scanner head needs to return to it's start position after each scan?

It wouldn't be faster if it had 2 start positions at the edges or just leave the head in the middle after each scan?

I think bidirectional scanning would be better for the lifespan of the arm motor too...

Comment: That's a great idea and if you build it people may beat a path to your door.  However, asking whether people think it's a good idea isn't an on-topic question.

Comment: the question really is about the reasoning of unidirectional scanning...

Comment: Questions about why things are designed the way they are instead of another way are generally outside the scope of the site.

Comment: can the question be moved to another site of the network (maybe Electrical Engineering)?

Comment: There are only a few sites that people can vote to migrate to (and those wouldn't be relevant).  You could flag a moderator and ask them to migrate it.  Electrical Engineering really wouldn't be an appropriate site (it's unlikely that the reason is electrical).  It seems more likely that it would relate to calibration or manufacturing cost.  I'm not sure there's a good SE site.  One thought, ask tech support at a couple of scanner manufacturers.  They would be closest to it and the most likely to have fact-based answers.

Comment: From what I know on how flatbed scanners were designed is that when scanning in one direction each scanned line corresponds to one caret position that in turn, relates to the addressing of the memory cells where image is stored. The addressing starts from 0 from one specific corner. If you move a caret in the opposite direction there would a be problem with addressing of memory cells because the "0 point" will be in the opposite corner (mirrored), so you need to make the system much more complicated to coupe with it.